# logging abstraction in .net framework class library

Tags: c#, serilog, ilogger

I'd like to create a .net framework (4.72) class library to be used inside a different project (also .net framework 4.72) that has Serilog as it's current logger.

In my class library my ctor has the following lines :

```
var loggerFactory = new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory();

var logProvider = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TcpServer>();
logProvider.LogDebug("Tcp Logger Init");
```

My 2nd project has a windows forms app with the following ctor :

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt").CreateLogger();
```

if I log directly from my windows forms project it works fine :

```
Log.Information("Test Info");
```

But I dont see the logs from the library I referenced into my windows forms project.

Any help is much appreciated on figuring out how to link between them
or any other project that I'll be using with the logging .